# A good web design book in Japanese

Tags: website-design, japanese

A question for the Japanese-speaking part of the Graphic Design society - is there a book on web design (mostly - non-technical aspects like usability) in Japanese that you could recommend?

There is a number of posts on this topic, but none of them is language-specific. I myself have read through "Do not make me think" and a couple of other really good books. Recently I was asked by a Japanese friend to recommend something. Unfortunately, my Japanese is not good enough to do the googling properly by myself (although I have tried) and her English - not good enough (yet) to read through a whole book.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I do have a suggestion. Try asking on Adobe's Dreamweaver forum and on graphicdesignforum.com. Both have Japanese participants and both are excellent resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two books by one of the foremost experts on usability, Jakob Nielsen. Both are very popular, and have been translated into many languages including Japanese. The first one is a bit old, but it's also "the number-one best-selling book about user interfaces", so definitely worth a look. Here they are...

**Designing Web Usability**

Author's Site: http://www.useit.com/jakob/webusability/

Amazon: [http://www.amazon.co.jp/exec/obidos/ASIN/4844355627](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/4844355627)

**Prioritizing Web Usability**

Update: *This one seems to have gotten bad reviews on Amazon, possibly due to the translation into Japanese. Hard to say if it's worth it.*

Author's Site: http://www.useit.com/prioritizing/

Amazon: [http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/4844358928/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/4844358928)

Comment: On Amazon.jp those books seems to have extremely bad reviews - perhaps the translation is bad.

Comment: The first book has quite decent reviews. The second, you may be correct about the translation. I have revised my answer.